# How to create a thread-safe rand.Source?

Tags: go, random, dependency-injection

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#NewSource) for the standard-library `rand.NewSource` function states that,

> Unlike the default Source used by top-level functions, this source is
>   not safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Is there a way to create a thread-safe `rand.Source`?

Context: I have a type with a method that may be called by multiple go-routines, and this method uses random numbers.  I want to support dependency injection for testing, so I can't use the default Source.

Answer (score 8):

It's typical to use a  [sync.Mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) to ensure that a value or values are not accessed concurrently.  Here's how to use a sync.Mutex to protect a rand.Source:

```
 var s = rand.NewSource(seed)
 var mu sync.Mutex

// lock/unlock when accessing source from a goroutine
mu.Lock()
i := s.Int63()
mu.Unlock()
```

The [rand.Rand](https://godoc.org/math/rand#Rand) does not support concurrent use.  If the application is using the rand.Source to create a rand.Rand, then protect the rand.Rand instead:

```
 var r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
 var mu sync.Mutex

// lock/unlock when accessing the rand from a goroutine
mu.Lock()
i := r.Int()
mu.Unlock()
```

The mutex used to protect the rand.Rand will also protect the rand.Source.

Answer (score 2):

After some sleuthing, I learned that the way to go is to protect the Source with a mutex.  The standard library even [contains an implementation](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go), `lockedSource`, but the relevant type [is not exported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/I6OyzJneuew).